# MySql, using LIKE to find an exact string

Tags: mysql

One of my tables has a field called MembersList, which is a list of names in the format `LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME.MIDDLENAMEorMIDDLEINITIAL` separated by semi-colons `(;)`. Example:

`DOE/JOHN.PETER;SMITH/ANDREW.K;FORD/HENRY.GEORGE`

Now a separate record might contain the name `DOE/JOHN.P`, but this person may not be the same as `DOE/JOHN.PETER` as in the above example, his P might stand for Paul or Philip, but the user of our service has entered him as simply `DOE/JOHN.P`.

If I say

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE MembersList LIKE '%DOE/JOHN.P%'
```

I will get the record for `DOE/JOHN.P` as well as the record for `DOE/JOHN.PETER` which is not what I want. The `DOE/JOHN.P` in this case should be treated as if his middle initial is actually P and only P. I've tried removing the second `%` but it returns nothing. What should my `LIKE` look like??

Does this make sense??

Comment: shouldn't you be using `=` then? as in `MembersList = 'DOE/JOHN.P'`?

Comment: no because it's semicolon delimited, not just one name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to test four conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM Events
WHERE MembersList = 'DOE/JOHN.P'
WHERE MembersList LIKE 'DOE/JOHN.P;%'
WHERE MembersList LIKE '%;DOE/JOHN.P'
WHERE MembersList LIKE '%;DOE/JOHN.P;%'
```

Alternately, if you can be sure that there are no commas in the string, you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM Events
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('DOE/JOHN.P', REPLACE(MembersList, ';', ','))
```

Unfortunately, FIND_IN_SET only works on comma-delimited lists, so you have to translate the semicolons to commas before using it.

All of these solutions are going to be slow. It would be better if you could maintain the members in a separate table (properly normalized), and build up the semicolon-delimited list only when you need it.

Comment: Thanks, of all the methods I tried from the answers provided, your FIND_IN_SET one seems to be the fastest (in my case anyways)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Events 
WHERE MembersList = 'DOE/JOHN.P' 
    or MembersList LIKE 'DOE/JOHN.P;%' 
    or MembersList LIKE '%;DOE/JOHN.P;%' 
    or MembersList LIKE '%;DOE/JOHN.P'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE CONCAT(';',MembersList,';') LIKE '%;DOE/JOHN.P;%'
```

The trick here is that we're looking for the semicolon delimiters, and we add a leading and trailing delimiter to the string we're searching.

Alternatively, you could avoid adding the leading and trailing delimiters, and test on four conditions. As a middle element in the string, the first element in the string, the last element in the string, and the only element in the string:

```
LIKE '%;foo;%'
LIKE 'foo;%'
LIKE '%;foo'
LIKE 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use regular expression instead of like to check if the name ends with a semi-colon or if the string is at the end

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE MembersList REGEXP 'DOE/JOHN\.P(;|$)'
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a little slow though for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is a wildcard. so if you put it at the end of a string (`Doe/John.P%`) it will find anything that ends with P and ANYTHING after that P.

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/wildcards-like-operator/wildcards-like-operator.php

So if you're using the `LIKE(%..%)` syntax and want to differentiate between: `LIKE 'DOE/JOHN.P'` and `LIKE 'DOE/JOHN.PETER'` You can't put a wildcard after the `P` because that will pick up anything that has `DOE/JOHN.P` in the string.

`%DOE/JOHN.P%` will pick up both `.P` and `.PETER`

`%DOE/JOHN.P` will pick up anything that *ends* in a `p`

---

You could combine them into an `or` statment:

`LIKE ... OR LIKE....` and do both to find both.

I would suggest using `=` instead.